# Getting foobar to shuffle between playlists

Tags: playback, foobar2000

I'm using foobar2000 0.9.6.9 as my default MP3 player, and I've got seven playlist tabs open right now. How do I get foobar to shuffle between all the songs in all seven playlists instead of just one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want just to create another playlist and drag-drop all the others playlist into the new one...

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not supported. I just make multiple playlists and then one combined one for this purpose. I'd suggest it on [their forums](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showforum=28) if you want to be heard. Developers read the forums as well as community members that are familiar with the SDK, so if the developers can't offer you a solution, an SDK user may offer to make you a plugin.